# Python Bokeh TapTool jump to corresponding DataTable row

Tags: python, bokeh

DISCLAIMER: I am new to plotting with Bokeh, and probably bad at programming in general (I just enjoy writing code and write handy scripts for use in my work.)

If I run the code example below as a bokeh server app, selecting a row on the data table will highlight the corresponding glyph on the plot; however, selecting a glyph on the plot with the TapTool will not highlight the corresponding row on the DataTable, is there a way to do this.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models import HoverTool, ResetTool, TapTool
from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable, TableColumn
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot

data = {'a': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 
       'b': [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]}
source = ColumnDataSource(data)
tools=[HoverTool(), TapTool(), ResetTool()]
columns = [TableColumn(field='a', title='A'),
          TableColumn(field='b', title='B')]

p1 = figure(plot_width=400, 
            plot_height=400,
            title='Example',
            x_axis_label='Example X', 
            y_axis_label='Example Y',
            tools=tools)

p1.circle_cross(x='a', 
                y='b', 
                source=source)

t1 = DataTable(columns=columns, 
              editable=False,
              height=200,
              width=400,
              fit_columns=True,
              source=source)

layout = gridplot([[p1],[t1]])

curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `scroll_to_selection= True, selectable = True` attributes to your `DataTable` like

```
t1 = DataTable(columns=columns, 
              editable=False,
              height=200,
              width=400,
              fit_columns=True,
              source=source,
              scroll_to_selection= True, selectable = True)
```